# Python Flask rename images on server, variable does not increment

Tags: python, flask

I use the following code to request the images:

```
@app.route("/user/zimmer-einstellen/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@check_confirmed
def for_image_upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        i = 1
        for key, file in request.files.iteritems():
            if file:
                filename = secure_filename(str(current_user.id) + "-bild-"+str(i)+".jpg")
                print filename              
                file.save(os.path.join(MYDIR + "/" + app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) 
                i = i + 1 
        return "images"
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I want to rename all images which I request and add at the end a counter, which is here `i`. So if I get 3 images they should be named like this:

```
1-bild-1.jpg
1-bild-2.jpg
1-bild-3.jpg
```

The problem is that `i` does not increment here and overwrite all files, so at the end only one file gets saved (the last one). I tried the code in a seperate new python file and it worked, so it must have something to do with the request probably?

And also if I don't rename the files and keep the original names, everything works fine, so multiple files are correctly requested and saved to the desired location.

Comment: Are you sure you're handling one request with all the files in it? Maybe you have multiple requests, each only having a single file. In this case you'd end up restarting the count from 1 every time and overwriting the previous images. Can you provide more details on how the request looks? You could for example use the [Flask Debug Toolbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-DebugToolbar) to get more insight into what's happening.

Comment: What is the output with `print key` ? This output may help you to check the request. And if the key is right,maybe you can use it to name your picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jan hinted, its a new request each time, so the `i = 0` always starts as `i = 0`. To solve this I simply looked into the folder and looped until the name was free:

```
for key, file in request.files.iteritems():
   if file:
       filename = secure_filename(str(current_user.id) + "-bild-1." + file.filename.split(".")[-1])

       i = 1
       while os.path.exists(os.path.join(MYDIR + "/" + app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)):
           filename = filename.split(".")[0][:-1] + str(i) + "." + filename.split(".")[1]  
                    i = i + 1

       file.save(os.path.join(MYDIR + "/" + app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```